# tvOS app - UIAlertController crashes with UIAlertAction

Tags: objective-c, crash, uialertcontroller, tvos, uialertaction

I have a single view tvOS app.  It has a collection view with 24 collectionviewcells.  When a collectionviewcell is selected, I trigger an alert.  I am using the default code from Apple's reference docs (pasted below).

```
 UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                               message:@"This is an alert."
                                               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" 
                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction]; // This is what I comment out
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I do not add the defaultAction to the alert (comment out [alert addAction:defaultAction];), the alert displays properly but no way to dismiss it.  When I add defaultAction to the alert, the alert displays with the 'OK' button, but get the dreaded SIGABRT error as soon as it appears on screen

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[_UIAlertControllerActionView image]: unrecognized selector
 sent to instance 0x7fe571ddee10'
```

Stack trace here:

```
2015-11-10 19:42:02.927 AppABC[1701:97632] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAlertControllerActionView image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fefd3ddaf10'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010de0a0b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d884deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010de126dd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd6005a ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd5fc08 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   IsItGood                            0x000000010d381170 __82-[ViewController collectionView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:]_block_invoke78 + 48
6   UIKit                               0x000000010e260df4 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 582
7   UIKit                               0x000000010e2612ec +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:] + 63
8   IsItGood                            0x000000010d380ca8 -[ViewController collectionView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:] + 536
9   UIKit                               0x000000010ea24e09 -[UICollectionView _didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:] + 1181
10  UIKit                               0x000000010eb15a5e _UIFocusEnvironmentDidUpdateFocus + 628
11  UIKit                               0x000000010e4fe102 __36-[UIScreen _updateFocusWithContext:]_block_invoke + 88
12  UIKit                               0x000000010e4fe161 __36-[UIScreen _updateFocusWithContext:]_block_invoke + 183
13  UIKit                               0x000000010e4fdb9f -[UIScreen _updateFocusWithContext:] + 1912
14  UIKit                               0x000000010e4feca9 -[UIScreen updateFocusIfNeeded] + 597
15  UIKit                               0x000000010e1c1e4a _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
16  UIKit                               0x000000010e1d53d9 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
17  UIKit                               0x000000010e1e1312 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd35ab7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd35a27 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd2b67b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd2af78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111582ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x000000010e1b608d UIApplicationMain + 171
24  AppABC                              0x000000010d3826af main + 111
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011050d9e9 start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @JustinVoss abbreviated stack trace since I don't get a lot of chars in comments...

- *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAlertControllerActionView image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88a0e287d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107176deb objc_exception_throw + 48
....
 25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109dff9e9 start + 1
 26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Yeah, that's not enough context to help. You should edit your question to include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your stack trace, your view controller is the problem here: you're trying to call the `image` method on something that doesn't implement that method, which is what causes this crash.

Look at your implementation of `-[ViewController collectionView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:]` and see where you're calling `image` on something: it look like you're assuming that object is of one type, when in reality it's another.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I am animating the newly focused collectionviewcell.  However, when I present the alert, the newly focused view is the alert which does not have image, movie title label, etc.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and created a new single view application, with one button and one button action. The button action contains your code snipped:

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {


    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                                   message:@"This is an alert."
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction]; // This is what I comment out
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It is working fine. The error must occur after dismissing the UIAlertViewController (this is done automatically after touching OK). This part of the code is missing. Add breakpoints to all relevant parts of your code and check, where it continues to track this error down.

Comment: I know the Apple code works.  I tried it in a test empty tvOS app as well and works as intended.  Unfortunately I don't get a chance to click on the 'OK' button.  The app crashes before it allows me to click on it.

Comment: It crashes directly in the line which you commented out?

Comment: No, it crashes while executing  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I wrote three different example

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func alertDone(sender: AnyObject) {
        let title = "Download Complete"
        let message = "Your game download completed"

        let buttonTitle = "OK"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { _ in
            print("Done was pressed")
        }

        alert.addAction(doneAction)

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    @IBAction func alertError(sender: AnyObject) {
        let title = "Error Complete"
        let message = "Please try again later."

        let okButton = "OK"
        let retryButton = "Retry Download"

        let alertError = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: okButton, style: .Default, handler: nil)

        let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: retryButton, style: .Cancel) { _ in
            print("Retry was pressed")
        }

        alertError.addAction(okAction)
        alertError.addAction(retryAction)

        presentViewController(alertError, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    @IBAction func alertConfirm(sender: AnyObject) {
        let title = "Are you sure"
        let message = "Please try again later."

        let cancelButton = "Cancel"
        let deleteButton = "Delete"

        let alertError = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButton, style: .Default, handler: nil)

        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: deleteButton, style: .Cancel) { _ in
            print("Retry was pressed")
        }

        alertError.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertError.addAction(deleteAction)

        presentViewController(alertError, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```